# Extend Swift Array to Filter Elements by Type

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, swift-extensions

How can a swift array be extended to access members of a particular type?

This is relevant if an array contains instances of multiple classes which inherit from the same superclass. Ideally it would enforce type checking appropriately.

---

#### Some thoughts and things that don't quite work:

Using the `filter(_:)` method works fine, but does enforce type safety. For example:

```
protocol MyProtocol { }
struct TypeA: MyProtocol { }
struct TypeB: MyProtocol { }

let myStructs:[MyProtocol] = [ TypeA(), TypeA(), TypeB() ]

let filteredArray = myStructs.filter({ $0 is TypeA })
```

the `filteredArray` contains the correct values, but the type remains `[MyProtocol]` not `[TypeA]`. I would expect replacing the last with `let filteredArray = myStructs.filter({ $0 is TypeA }) as! [TypeA]` would resolve that, but the project fails with `EXEC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` which I do not understand. Perhaps type casting arrays is not possible?

Ideally this behavior could be wrapped up in an array extension. The following doesn't compile:

```
extension Array {
    func objectsOfType<T:Element>(type:T.Type) -> [T] {
        return filter { $0 is T } as! [T]
    }
}
```

Here there seem to be at least two problems: the type constraint `T:Element` doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure what the correct way to add a constraint based on a generic type. My intention here is to say `T` is a subtype of `Element`. Additionally there are compile time errors on line 3, but this could just be the same error propagating.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SequenceType` has a `flatMap()` method which acts as an "optional filter":

```
extension SequenceType {
    /// Return an `Array` containing the non-nil results of mapping
    /// `transform` over `self`.
    ///
    /// - Complexity: O(*M* + *N*), where *M* is the length of `self`
    ///   and *N* is the length of the result.
    @warn_unused_result
    @rethrows public func flatMap<T>(@noescape transform: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> T?) rethrows -> [T]
}
```

Combined with matt's suggestion to use `as?` instead of `is` you
can use it as

```
let myStructs:[MyProtocol] = [ TypeA(), TypeA(), TypeB() ]
let filteredArray = myStructs.flatMap { $0 as? TypeA }
```

Now the type of `filteredArray` is inferred as `[TypeA]`.

As an extension method it would be

```
extension Array {
    func objectsOfType<T>(type:T.Type) -> [T] {
        return flatMap { $0 as? T }
    }
}

let filteredArray = myStructs.objectsOfType(TypeA.self)
```

Note: For **Swift >= 4.1,** replace `flatMap` by `compactMap`.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of testing (with `is`) how about casting (with `as`)?

```
let myStructs:[MyProtocol] = [ TypeA(), TypeA(), TypeB() ]
var filteredArray = [TypeA]()
for case let t as TypeA in myStructs {filteredArray.append(t)}
```

Comment: Pls note: this is Swift 2.0.

Comment: Or: `let filteredArray = myStructs.flatMap { $0 as? TypeA }`

Comment: @MartinR Yes, I always forget about `flatMap` as a form of filtering. It's badly named. I have actually put in a bug report requesting that it be deleted, as everything it does can now be done more clearly in some other way.

Comment: @MartinR Hooray! `flatMap(_:)` works just fine. That's not something that stood out to me.

Comment: @MartinR you should enter that as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Casting arrays does not work in Swift. This is because arrays in Swift use generics, just like you can't cast a custom class, where only the type `T` changes. (`class Custom<T>`, `Custom<Int>() as! Custom<String>`).

What you can do is create an extension method to Array, where you define a method like this:

```
extension Array {
    func cast<TOut>() -> [TOut] {
        var result: [TOut] = []
        for item in self where item is TOut {
            result.append(item as! TOut)
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: Got it. Using a more functional approach like `.flatMap(_:)` which creates a new array avoids that anyway. Is there a reason casts between array types are not possible?

Comment: Casting between array types is a deep operation, it requires verifying that every element has the appropriate type in order to maintain type-safety.  My guess is that they just didn't want to hide that level of hit.

Answer (score 0):

I think the canonical FP answer would be to use filter, as you are, in combination with map:

```
let filteredArray = myStructs.filter({ $0 is TypeA }).map({ $0 as! TypeA })
```

alternatively, you can use reduce:

```
let filtered2 = myStructs.reduce([TypeA]()) {
    if let item = $1 as? TypeA {
        return $0 + [item]
    } else {
        return $0
    }
}
```

or, somewhat less FP friendly since it mutates an array:

```
let filtered3 = myStructs.reduce([TypeA]()) { ( var array, value )  in
    if let item = value as? TypeA {
        array.append(item)
    }
    return array
}
```

which can actually be shortened into the once again FP friendly flatMap:

```
let filtered4 = myStructs.flatMap { $0 as? TypeA }
```

And put it in an extension as:

```
extension Array {
    func elementsWithType<T>() -> [T] {
        return flatMap { $0 as? T }
    }
}

let filtered5 : [TypeA] = myStructs.elementsWithType()
```

Comment: Which, of course boils down to the answer Matt and Martin arrived at I was getting it all gussied up :)