# Swift: filter array of Any objects with a certain type

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I have an array (Any type) with list of custom object (example object: Vehicle, Parking, Motorbike).

I need to filter this array with a specific type: example Vehicle.
Can you help me?

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: `let filtered = array.filter({ $0.isVehicle})`?

Comment: @Larme you meant `$0 is Vehicle` note that this would result in `[Any]`. What he needs is `array.compactMap({ $0 as? Vehicle})`

Comment: I meant `$0 is Vehicle` indeed. It should work, and filtered would by `[Any]`, right? I understood that the author didn't mentioned that he/she needed a `[Vehicle]` at the end.

Comment: Related: [Extend Swift Array to Filter Elements by Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112114/extend-swift-array-to-filter-elements-by-type).

Comment: Filter not work on Any array.
Only function available is flatMap but not works

let filtered4 = self.objectsList.flatMap { $0 as? Vehicle }

Comment: @LuigiMarino Can you explain what you mean by "not work"?  Filter should work on all arrays, and what result were you getting from flatMap?

Answer (score 8):

With `compactMap` and `as?`:

```
let values: [Any] = [1, "string", 0.0, ["array values"]]

let strings = values.compactMap { $0 as? String } // ["string"]
```

Make sure to do this as soon as possible (as soon as data comes into the system). You should not need `[Any]` as a class property, for example. If you feel you need that, you probably have mis-designed your data model and actually wanted an enum. `Any` is not a proper type in Swift; it exists to handle certain edge cases, mostly involving Objective-C, and very special cases like `print`. If you don't mean "absolutely any type at all is ok here," then you don't mean `Any`.

Comment: Filter and compact map not work on Any array.
Only function available is flatMap but not works
let filtered4 = self.objectsList.flatMap { $0 as? Vehicle }

Comment: @LuigiMarino `flatMap` was renamed (for this use; not all uses) to `compactMap` in Swift 4. If you're using Swift 3, your code is equivalent.